# Modified Kruskal's Algorithm

Tags: graphs

I have a connected graph, each vertex has a cost.

I want to slice the graph into as many components as possible, but each component should have a cost (sum of costs of vertices) at least C.

I think it should be possible with a modified Kruskal's algorithm. Each vertex is a component by itself. Then, I find the cheapest vertex and join it with the cheapest neighbour, until there are components with a cost smaller than C.

But how do I track components and their costs, to know when to stop? Is there a Union-Find data structure, that returns the same representative during the whole algorithm (I could use the representative to identify a component).

Comment: Your problem is NP-hard, by reduction from PARTITION. Details left to you.

Comment: The problem is also strongly NP-hard as it can be seen by reducing from 3-PARTION. It helps to assume that each element of the 3-PARTITION instance is strictly between $C/4$ and $C/2$, where $C$ is the target value, thus forcing each group with sum $C$ to contain exactly $3$ elements. It is easy to come up with a graph that can be partitioned in $n/3$ components of weight at least $C$ if and only if there is a solution to the 3-PARTITION instance.